# Entropy Change for incompressible Solid

Tags: thermodynamics

How can I prove $$\Delta s=mc \ln \frac{T_2}{T_1}$$ for an incompressible solid starting from $t\cdot ds\cdot dh-v\cdot dp$? Also does this $t\cdot ds=dh-v\cdot dp$ equation hold good for both compressible and incompressible substance?

Comment: When you say "incompressible," do you mean that the specific volume is independent of both T and P, or do you mean that it is just independent of P but not T?

Comment: @Chester Miller :  It is independent  of both T and P.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$ds=\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial T}\right)_PdT+\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial P}\right)_TdP$$
But, from one of the Maxwell equations, $$\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial P}\right)_T=-\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P$$But, for an incompressible solid, this is zero.  So, s is a function only of T, and $$dh=T\frac{ds}{dT}dT+\left(v+T\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial P}\right)_T\right)dP=T\frac{ds}{dT}dT+vdP=C_pdT+vdP$$Therefore, $$\frac{ds}{dT}=\frac{C_p}{T}$$